# How to produce color image using edge detected images?

Tags: image-processing, python, opencv, numpy

Hi I am trying to produce an image which is a combination of multiple images such as in focus stacking. Now I have 6 photos and I want to produce a final image such that the final image uses blocks of individual images with maximum value of the block. 
But I want to do edge detection of these 6 images first and based on the maximum edges produce a final image such that the final image has the maximum edges from the combination of all images. But the final image produced should be a color image and not in the edge detected form. Is it possible to do so?
[Images can be accessed here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F9LLLgSLNLuKTtRnEeoQgmh7t61qYG_Q)

Comment: You don't need to explicitly perform an edge detection for this. You can just use the gradients (e.g. sobel) to guide you during fusing. Do you have sample images?

Comment: Yes I'll link them in the question. @TolgaBirdal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thanks for sharing this problem. I hope it can foster some good discussions here at stack-exchange. I guess this problem is commonly called *Multi-Focus Multi-Image Fusion* (MF-MIF).

Let's look at all the images together with their grayscale histograms and the gradient magnitude (information content in each image):

[image]
[image]

As the original question requires an edge-based (or rather gradient as I take it) method, I will follow the idea presented in the following paper:

> S. Paul, I.S. Sevcenco, P. Agathoklis, "Multi-exposure and Multi-focus
>   image fusion in gradient domain", Journal of Circuits, Systems, and
>   Computers, Vol. 25, No. 10 (2016), DOI: 10.1142/S0218126616501231
>   https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/114b/835c5ea86e93efff1027cd6da7188c0cc92f.pdf

Essentially, the method aims to *blend the gradients of the luminance components of the
input images using the maximum gradient magnitude at each pixel location and then to obtain the fused luminance using a Haar wavelet-based image reconstruction technique*. The algorithm also *includes a Poisson solver at each resolution to eliminate artifacts that may appear due to the non-conservative nature of the resulting gradient*.

The official source code of the method is given in [this github repository](https://github.com/sujoyp/gradient-domain-imagefusion) and in your, kind of challenging dataset, the output looks like the following:

[image]

I am not sure if this is a sufficiently good output, but I bet further investigations can quickly lead to improved results. A small observation: The first image seems to be quite sharp. It seems like it has a global focus and already looks (only looks though) better than the resulting image.

Comment: thanks for sharing this. It does exactly what I wanted. Even though the output I expected can still use some improvement. Maybe aligning the images first could produce better results.

Comment: definitely. I added a small paragraph in the end. the first image looks sharp already : ). I neither know the capture properties nor the desired outcome of course.